# HTML Buttons behaves weirdly on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So say I have this HTML code:

```js
function sendMain() {
  swal({
    title: "Preparando para mandar Email...",
    text: "Clique em 'OK' para mandar o Email.",
    type: "info",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  }, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      swal("Redirecionando!");
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="send" onclick="sendMain()">Mandar</button>
```

Where swal is the SweetAlert show alert function.
The thing is: when I click it, it shows the message for 1/4 of second and then goes to the top of the page and adds "?" to the end of the page's URL. What is wrong?

Comment: Try adding `return false ` to the end of the sendMain function.

Comment: maybe a library mix bug ? have you tried to isolate libraries ?

Comment: Thank you, @SergeSeredenko. It works better now, but it still goes to the top of the page.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Não acredito que esse seja o problema, visto que estou usando apenas JQuery e SweetAlert, mas obrigado por comentar!

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeida this is an english only site. Please use english only.
He said: I don't believe that's the problem, once I'm using only Jquery e SweetAlert, but thanks for commenting.

Comment: I think sweetalert scrolls top. Try running swal() from console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a `type` for your button, so by default it is a submit button. And the default behaviour for a submit button is to try to submit its form which makes the page reload. Add the following attribute:

```
type="button"
```

Then the button will have no default action and thus will only do whatever you specify via Javascript.

Comment: Or don't put the button inside a `<form>`.

Comment: @Barmar - True. Though I like to include the type anyway just to be thorough (or in case I later add a form). If the OP's button isn't in a form then my answer is wrong about the cause of their problem.